# ¿Cómo hacer visible una firma digital en un pdf con TCPDF y PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, openssl, firma-digital, tcpdf

estoy intentando firmar digitalmente un archivo PDF con PHP y la librería TCPDF. El problema viene cuando genero el PDF, puesto que no me hace visible la firma. Lo único que he logrado ha sido crear un recuadro para firmarlo con Adobe Reader. Pero mi idea no es esa, sino que se genere el fichero PDF con la firma directamente incrustada en el, sin necesidad de ningún otro programa.

El código que uso es el siguiente:

```
<?php
//Incluimos los archivos de la libreria tcpdf
require_once('tcpdf/TCPDF-main/examples/tcpdf_include.php');
require_once ('tcpdf/TCPDF-main/tcpdf.php');


// creamos el documento PDF
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);



// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Ivan Martinez');
$pdf->SetTitle('Prueba HolaMundo');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// Encabezado de serie
//$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 001', PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));
//$pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128));

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

//set certificated file
$certificate = 'file://'.realpath('tcpdf.crt');

// set additional information
$info = array(
    'Name' => 'PruebaIvan',
    'Location' => 'Ayuntamiento',
    'Reason' => 'Testeando firma',
);


$pdf->setSignature($certificate, $certificate, 'tcpdfdemo', '', 2, $info);

// set default font subsetting mode
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

// Set font
// dejavusans is a UTF-8 Unicode font, if you only need to
// print standard ASCII chars, you can use core fonts like
// helvetica or times to reduce file size.
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);


// Add a page
// This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
$pdf->AddPage();

// set text shadow effect
$pdf->setTextShadow(array('enabled'=>true, 'depth_w'=>0.2, 'depth_h'=>0.2, 'color'=>array(196,196,196), 'opacity'=>1, 'blend_mode'=>'Normal'));

// Set some content to print
$html = <<<EOD
Documento creado por Ivan Martinez;
EOD;

// Print text using writeHTMLCell()
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);


$pdf->setSignatureAppearance(200, 170, 40, 20);

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

// *** set an empty signature appearance ***
$pdf->addEmptySignatureAppearance(180, 80, 15, 15);


// ---------------------------------------------------------

// Close and output PDF document
// This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
$pdf->Output('pruebaFirma.pdf', 'I');

?>
```

He probado a quitar la sentencia `$pdf->addEmptySignatureAppearance(180, 80, 15, 15);`  pero no ha servido para nada.

Gracias de antemano, un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Yo también hago lo mismo, descargo mi reporte con los cuadros de firma y aplico la firma digital con Adobe Reader. Creo que el problema abarca en el certificado que soporte TCPDF es CRT y lo que intenté implantar es un CER. En tu caso el crt te lo brindaron o sólo cambiaste la extensión?

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/300697)

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).